# CUDA speed optimization

Tags: performance, cuda

I have developed an application in CUDA for modular exponentiation and it performs very well for 512-bit integers. This multi precision integers are stored in 16 32-bit words.
Some concepts I use in order to achieve 2.5 - 3.2 speedup comparing to OpenSSL modular exponentiation approach:

- `__shared__` memory
- CUDA memory align
- PTX code for 32-bit addition, multiplication
- unrolling

All good by now, but trying to extend the integers to 1024 bits, the performance decreases dramatically to 0.1 - 0.3, and the only difference is the memory size needed to store an integer - now 32 x 32-bit words. Not to mention the 2048-bit version which is hundreds of times slower.

I have to say that when I want to compute 1000 modular exponentiations (`r = a^x mod n`), for example, I just send all the operands to my kernel, that means 512000 Bytes of memory.
My question: Why this minor changing is influencing the performance so much?
I use Nvidia Geforce GT 520mx, Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit.

Comment: Without a [mcve] it is hard/impossible to tell. One point you might want to look in is register spilling. But this is just speculation....

Comment: Register spilling would also have been my first guess. Compile the PTX with ` nvcc -Xptxas=-v ...` to receive information about the register usage, maybe it helps.

Comment: Ok, I will take it into account!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to tell without a minimal testing source code, but you could run into several limitations while increasing the size of your data :

- Registers
- Shared memory / L1 cache
- Occupancy

And maybe a lot of others that I am forgetting.

Profiling your application could be very, very helpful. If you use Visual Studio, Nvidia NSIGHT can analyse the execution of your application and give you a lot of helpful information :

- Blocks, threads, warps
- Device theoretical and achieved occupancy
- Multiprocessors activity
- etc

And even [draw some charts](http://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/index.html#developertools/desktop/nsight/analysis/report/cudaexperiments/kernellevel/issueefficiency.htm%3FTocPath%3DDeveloper%2520Tools%7CDesktop%2520Developer%2520Tools%7CNVIDIA%2520Nsight%2520Visual%2520Studio%2520Edition%7CNVIDIA%2520Nsight%2520Visual%2520Studio%2520Edition%25205.0%7CAnalysis%2520Tools%7CCUDA%2520Experiments%7CKernel-Level%2520Experiments%7C_____5) for you to view easily where is your bottleneck.

See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36477199/6172231) on how to make Nsight run and analyse your application for performance analysis.

Comment: thanks for suggestions. I have the possibility to test it with Nsight. Even a minimal example would be too big to post here and also difficult to understand. I will try to use Nsight and I will come back with an answer.

Comment: @DaniGrosu If you have the possibility to try with Nsight, then yes do it ! Surely you will get additional helpful info.